# how to add spaces between array items javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, split, tostring

I am a beginner at javascript so I appreciate any help/advice given.

My issue here is that I'm trying to figure out how to add space between items in the times[] array which holds the values for showtimes for each movie object. I tried to split at the comma (",") but that isn't working. When I tried splitting at ("pm") that worked. I also figured out a way to add space in the showtimes values themselves, but I thought that there must be a better way to go about it. Any thoughts? thanks!

```
window.onload = init;


function Movie(title, year, showtimes) { 
  this.title = title;
  this.year = year;
  this.showtimes = showtimes;
  }

  function init() {
    var darkKnight = new Movie("The Dark Knight Rises", "2012", ["1pm,", "2pm,", "3pm,"]);
    var takeThisWaltz = new Movie ("Take This Waltz", "2012", ["4pm", "5pm","6pm"]);
    var watchmen = new Movie("Watchmen", "2009", ["7pm","8pm","9pm"]); 

    var movieList = [darkKnight, takeThisWaltz, watchmen]


    for(var i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) { 
    var theObj = movieList[i];
    var times = [movieList[i].showtimes] 
      for(var j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
      var str = times[i];     
      } 
    makeResult();    }


    function makeResult() {             
    var list = document.getElementById("movieList"); 
    var li = document.createElement("li");          
    li.innerHTML = "title: " + movieList[i].title + " year: " + movieList[i].year + " showtimes: " + times[0].toString().split(",");
    list.appendChild(li); }


 }
```

Answer (score 86):

the `array.join` function takes an optional `delimiter` parameter which will seperate the elements by the delimiter. A simple example:

```
var showtimes = ["1pm", "2pm", "3pm"];
var showtimesAsString = showtimes.join(', '); // gives "1pm, 2pm, 3pm"
```

Comment: I made the mistake of saving my joined array into another array instead of a string, which didn't fail but output unwanted commas.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const names = ["alice", "bob", "charlie", "danielle"]
    
    
    const capitalized = names.map((name) => {
        return name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)
    })
    
    console.log(capitalized)
```

```
["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Danielle"]
```

Comment: the question was about spaces, not capitalization. are you sure you replied to the right question?